# Calling pgf rand inside pgfmathsetmacro creates extra text

Tags: pgfmath, random-numbers, pgfmathparse

I am using pgf and tikz for some latex questions. The code below illustrates a problem I am facing: when I use the rand function from pgf inside a pgfmathsetmacro I get some extra text at the beginning of the example text (in my case, I get Y1Y1). If I remove the call to rand then I do not get that extra text, but or course I do not get random values. I have read the docs but haven't found yet a clue. What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\FACTOR}{0.9}
%\pgfmathsetmacro{\QA}{9.0*(1 + \FACTOR*3)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\QA}{9.0*(1 + \FACTOR*rand} % generates spurious Y1Y1 or similar text
TEST-TEXT \pgfmathparse{3*\QA}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `/pgf/fpu/output format=sci` to your `pgfkeys` setting

Comment: Yeah, @ChristianHupfer, thanks, that made it. Could you please elaborate a bit why that is needed even if I do not use pgfmathparse etc and just use TEST-TEXT?

Comment: I can't really explain it. I think, it is the cause of the `fpu` library. I doubt that you need that library at all here

Comment: Yeah, this is just a MWE for a more complex setup, that is why fpu seems odd. If you wish you can add your first comment as answer and i will mark it as such.

Comment: No, it is better to wait for someone, that can answer this really. It was a comment by me, only